# iOS SDK: set background color of button by its tag number

Tags: ios, sdk

I have 4 button with tag number: 0, 1, 2, 3. I want to change its color when clicking on it. So here is what I am doing:

```
switch ([sender tag]) {
        case 0:
                   [myButton0 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
                   break;
        case 1:
           [myButton1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
                    break;
        case 2:
           [myButton2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
            break;
        case 3:
                   [myButton3 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
           break;
}
```

my question is that if there is any way to shorten the code, like we set background color by it tag number?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what i am doing. I have created a category on UIColor for colorWithHexValue. You can use your code.

```
 [signInButton setTitle:@"Sign In" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
signInButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15];
gradientLayer = [UIColor setGradientEffect:signInButton initialColor:0x797979 endColor:0x424242];
[[signInButton layer] insertSublayer:gradientLayer atIndex:0]; 
[signInButton setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithHexValue:0xFFFFFF] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[signInButton setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithHexValue:0x000000] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Please use

```
enum {
UIControlStateNormal       = 0,                       
UIControlStateHighlighted  = 1 << 0,                  // used when UIControl isHighlighted is set
UIControlStateDisabled     = 1 << 1,
UIControlStateSelected     = 1 << 2,                  // flag usable by app (see below)
UIControlStateApplication  = 0x00FF0000,              // additional flags available for application use
UIControlStateReserved     = 0xFF000000               // flags reserved for internal framework use
```

};